# Read Json request inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, json

I am using the following request to close php session.

And the question is how to read the json request inside logout.php php file where I will have something like this to happen `logout.php?logout=true`.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
var data = {
  var1:"logout=true",
};
var querystring = require("querystring");
var qs = querystring.stringify(data);
var qslength = qs.length;
var options = {
  hostname: "www.url.com",
  port: 80,
  path: "logout.php",
  method: 'POST',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': qslength
  }
};
var buffer = "";
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
   buffer+=chunk;
 });
  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log(buffer);
  });
});
req.write(qs);
req.end();
```

Comment: This will generate a very very ordinary POST request for your php script.

Comment: May help if they actual sent the data.  Never added the `data` var to `options` var.....  Just saying.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - (0) actual --> actually. (1) `req.write(sq);` outputs the data. Am I mistaken?

Comment: `$_POST['var1']` should contain the string `"logout=true"`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix no `data` option exists ~ https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback